Foreign movie on cable (Showtime), probably from the mid 80's
It's a long shot, but here goes ...
I am looking for a movie I was years ago on cable (Showtime), showed around the mid to late 80's.  It was probably originally a Spanish production, but obviously I don't know the title.
What I remember of the plot is this:

Multiple sub plots
One of the locations is a beach, very busy with tourists and such, looks to be Mexico or South America (Brazil ?).  Reminded me or Rio De Janeiro or Acapulco.
Scene: Couple (the main characters) walking along the beach, background music was I believe LIPPS INC "Funkytown", or perhaps Matthew Wilder "Nobody's Gunna Break My Stride".
Subplot: Young boy with dyed hair streak (green or blue) is exploring his sexuality, in that he starts sneaking out at night to meet guys.  His father chases him down and confronts him, Father does not approve.
Subplot: Older lady lives up a hill/mountain.  Someone stole jewelry (maybe a necklace) from her, and it eventually gets returned.

I remember it being pretty racy for the time, and seem to remember thinking the "sexy bits" were heavily edited.
Anyway, if any of this sounds familiar, I'm open to any leads.
